Executing multiple WITH clauses inside a T-SQL function
How do I include multiple WITH clauses inside of a T-SQL function?
So I have these WITH clauses:
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        dbo.mydb
    WHERE 
        condition
),
b AS (
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            big switch case   
        FROM 
            dbo.myotherdb
        LEFT JOIN 
            dbo.anotherone
        WHERE 
            condition
),
c AS (
    SELECT 
        a.*
    FROM 
        a
    LEFT JOIN 
        b
)

Now, I would like to use my c clause inside of a function as such:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction() RETURNS DECIMAL
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyVariable DECIMAL
    SET @MyVariable = (
                        CASE
                        WHEN ( 
                            SELECT TOP(1) c.something 
                            FROM c AS c 
                            ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                        WHEN (
                            SELECT TOP(1) c.something
                            FROM c AS c 
                            WHERE c.something = 2
                            ) IS NOT NULL THEN 2 - dbo.otherfunction()
                        END)
RETURN @MyVariable
END GO

Where do I have to put my WITH clauses? Wherever I put them, I get a syntax error. Before my function declaration, inside after de the begin, before the select in the parantheses.
Edit: I modified my example function to look more like the real problem I have. Instead of a select statement, I need to do a switch case.
Okay so this is what the solution was:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction() RETURNS DECIMAL
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyVariable DECIMAL
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        dbo.mydb
    WHERE 
        condition
),
b AS (
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            big switch case   
        FROM 
            dbo.myotherdb
        LEFT JOIN 
            dbo.anotherone
        WHERE 
            condition
),
c AS (
    SELECT 
        a.*
    FROM 
        a
    LEFT JOIN 
        b
)
    SELECT @MyVariable = (
                        CASE
                        WHEN ( 
                            SELECT TOP(1) c.something 
                            FROM c AS c 
                            ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                        WHEN (
                            SELECT TOP(1) c.something
                            FROM c AS c 
                            WHERE c.something = 2
                            ) IS NOT NULL THEN 2 - dbo.otherfunction()
                        END)
RETURN @MyVariable
END GO


Mismatched parentheses in your first query.  You have 7 parentheses.

don't use DECIMAL without precision / size, it should be DECIMAL(19,12) or whatever you want

You put them inside the function, as that's where the statement go. Presumbly (you don't show your attempt(s)) you tried WITH CTE AS (...) SET @Variable... however a CTE cannot be followed by a SET, it must be a SELECT or DML statement. You also have a syntax error in your CTE, as you don't close the parenthesis for your derived table, nor name it.
Fixing these it would look like this:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction ()
RETURNS decimal --(p,s) required
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyVariable decimal; --(p,s) required
    WITH
    a AS
        (SELECT *
         FROM dbo.mydb
         WHERE condition = 1),
    b AS
        (SELECT *
         FROM (SELECT bigswitch AS cased
               FROM dbo.myotherdb
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.anotherone ON 1 = 1
               WHERE condition = 1) a 
    ),
    c AS
        (SELECT a.*
         FROM a
              LEFT JOIN b ON 1 = 1)
    SELECT @MyVariable = c.firstdecimal
    FROM c;
    RETURN @MyVariable;
END;
GO

Though this is unlikely a good idea, use an inline Table Value Function instead:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction ()
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN WITH
           a AS
               (SELECT *
                FROM dbo.mydb
                WHERE condition = 1),
           b AS
               (SELECT *
                FROM (SELECT big AS switchcase
                      FROM dbo.myotherdb
                           LEFT JOIN dbo.anotherone ON 1 = 1
                      WHERE condition = 1) a --Alias goes here
           ),
           c AS
               (SELECT a.*
                FROM a
                     LEFT JOIN b ON 1 = 1)
    SELECT c.firstdecimal
    FROM c;
GO

